# Petición AJAX y problemas con rutas en producción

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Resulta que estoy haciendo un `request` mediante `AJAX` a un archivo `.php` y la ruta es la siguiente:

`url: 'assets/db/verificarEmail.php'`

**Todo funciona bien en local**, pero al subirlo a un servidor no funciona, y el error que me tira la consola de chrome es el siguiente:

> POST http://pedrofumero.com/memoria/assets/db/verificarEmail.php 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación el código `AJAX` implementado:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'assets/db/verificarEmail.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'email=' + $(this).val()
            })
            .done(function(data) {
              if(data.err) {
                Swal.fire({
                    position: 'top-end',
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'El email ingresado ya se encuentra registado',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 2500
                  });
                  $('#password').attr('disabled','');
                $(this).removeClass('border-success');
              }

            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                console.log('Falló!');
                console.log( data ); 
            })
```

El problema tiene que ver con las rutas, pero no he logrado dar con la solución, cómo se puede solventar?

Comment: Definitivamente no es la ruta, tu servidor te esta diciendo que hay un error interno, por lo que si llega a la ruta, la consola a de dar mas detalles del error ya que tienes `.fail`en tu `ajax`

Comment: El problema no es AJAX, el problema es el archivo **.PHP** que has subido al servidor, tienes un error **500**. Estas accediendo al archivo desde AJAX pero este esta dando ese error. ¿Puedes incluir el codigo PHP?